# How to add space between UITableView sections?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

How does iOS edit contact `UITableView` add space between sections while still showing previous sections' last cells' separators?

In the screenshot below, the first cell of the third section is highlighted. How do I add that white space above it without hiding the separator underneath the "add phone" cell above it? I tried adding a white section header, but that hides the separator of the cell above it.

[image]

Comment: How do you know they are separators?

Comment: I don't, but they look exactly like them. I added more detail to my question to clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: What I'm saying is, how do you know that those gray lines are not drawn as part of the cells? That's what I do. I find it much easier to do that, and take control of the lines, than to use the table cell separators.

Comment: I don't. Custom drawing every separator is probably a better idea (in case Apple decides to change the height of their separators) than just drawing one of them as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iOS 15 you can add padding to the section header

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As a hack, I just added a separator to the header view.

```
// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return section == 0 ? UITableViewAutomaticDimension : 24
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        return nil
    } else {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.separatorInset.left, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0.5))
        separator.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
        separator.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor
        view.addSubview(separator)
        return view
    }
}
```

Please answer if you have a clean & simple solution.

Answer (score 5):

If your concern is about only for spacing then try below code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

Comment: what about if the section has footer?